# Running Sikuli X from command line

Tags: command-line, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I have figured out how to run Sikuli X from command line using:

@start C:\SikuliX\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Automation\test.sikuli

exit

My problem is when it runs it opens up another command window, runs the program and finishes but then doesn't close the command window it opens. I was wondering if anyone knew how to close that command window it opens? I could get Sikuli to do the whole find the exit button and close it like that but i don't want to do that for fear something might not shutdown right.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to the answer below i figured it out. All you have to do is alter the runIDE.cmd that comes with Sikuli and simply add exit at the end of the program and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:  it depends if the executable is a command line program or a gui window.

```
@echo off
start "" /w /b C:\SikuliX\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Automation\test.sikuli
exit
```

Actually, I see it is a batch file, so try this:

```
@echo off
call C:\SikuliX\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Automation\test.sikuli
exit
```

Comment: Ok so thanks but i didn't work. So to be more precise i am running this from a batch file. The batch file opens a command window like always which then proceeds to run the sikuli script. your suggesetions do stop the first command window but the sikuli script opens its another command window which then doesn't close. It is more of a problem with sikuli than with command prompt

Comment: `runIDE.cmd` must use the start command inside it.  If you add that batch file to your question then it should be clearer.

Comment: thank you for making me think of that. All i had to do was add exit to the end of the bat file runIDE.cmd and it exited itself after it was done. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Running Sikuli scripts from command line

**without arguments**

open command prompt.

type cd "Sikuli directory" and enter

type the following command to run :

```
 runIDE.cmd -r "sikuli script path"
```

**with argument**

```
 runIDE.cmd -r "sikuli script path" -args "a1" "a2" "a3"
```